# How to call Generic Inquiry through web service API?

Tags: c#, acumatica

In order to get Location record based on primary keys, e.g. Business Account ID (BAccountID) and Location ID (LocationID) through Web Service, I was trying to call Generic Inquiry through SM208000Submit as @Gabriel suggested in another question ([Filtering on Customer Screen does not use more than one filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26662651/filtering-on-customer-screen-does-not-use-more-than-one-filter)), instead of CR303010Export API since I had difficulties to pass BAccountID and LocationID to CR303010Export  as filters, which I put in another question([How would I search "Location" based on primary keys such as BAccountID and LocationID through Web Service API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30109471/how-would-i-search-location-based-on-primary-keys-such-as-baccountid-and-locat)) but no any luck to get response yet so far.

In this case I created a Generic Inquiry with two parameters (AccountID and LocationID), which I called it "GetLocationByAccountAndID" and it worked perfectly fine when I tried to "view Inquiry" with values assigned to those two parameters; however, when it came to calling it through Web Service, I got problem again - how am I supposed to specify my inquiry title, pass parameters and get result?

I guess I should do something like:

```
SM208000Content SM208000 = context.SM208000GetSchema();

context.SM208000Clear();

List<Command> cmds = new List<Command>();

cmds.Add(new Value { Value = "GetLocationByCustomerAndID", LinkedCommand = SM208000.InquirySummary.InquiryTitle});

cmds.Add(new Value { Value = "8145", LinkedCommand = SM208000.Parameters.AvailableValues });  //probably not right
cmds.Add(new Value { Value = "9388", LinkedCommand = SM208000.Parameters.AvailableValues });  //probably not right

       ......  //what should I do to set parameters and specify those fields in resultgrid?


cmds.Add(SM208000.Actions.ViewInquiry);

SM208000Content[] SM208000content = context.SM208000Submit(cmds.ToArray());
```

By the way, does anybody know whether there is a specification for this whole web service API thing, other than those examples in that development Guide ?

Any help would be really appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once they are added to the site map, generic inquiries become accessible via web services like any other screen. You go to Help->Web Service to retrieve the web service URL, but it follows the same pattern as normal screens. Ex: https://acumatica.velixo.com/Soap/GI000005.asmx

You can find a complete training course on Acumatica web services at http://acumaticaopenuniversity.com/courses/developer-certification/t900-acumatica-web-services/

Comment: Thank you so much, @Gabriel! I didn't know I would have to make it into "SiteMap" since that field is not mandatory...anyway, I just tried and got screen id and I will try to call this screen later. In terms of training course you pointed to, I did download that PDF, but unfortunately it's exactly same as the document in Accumatica - I have read through it , which did help me to understand the basics of the web services but there are a lot of details missing...I would expect a much better document.  Thanks for letting me know anyway.